# Trying to use ifelse in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to mutate a column based on value. But unfortunately, the column value are replaced with some random values. any clue about where am I doing wrong. Th following is the code, that I am using

```
dataset %>%
  mutate(Code = ifelse(Code == 80, 20, Code))
```

The answer, I am expecting is  if code = 80 replace it with 20, if not assign same value. 
But unfortuately, Its been replaced with random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `Code` is `factor`.  Convert it to `character` or `numeric` (after converting to `character`) would solve the issue.  The values that are shown are the integer storage mode value

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
   mutate(Code = ifelse(as.character(Code) == 80, 20, as.character(Code)))
```

---

NOTE: The class of columns can be found from the `str` itself`

```
str(dataset)
```

or use

```
sapply(dataset, class)
```

Comment: Also `glimpse(dataset)`